# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) and all R's in red

Tags: java, android, xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the java main class it appears all the "R" in red and they say "cannot resolve symbol 'R'", all the tags are closed in the xml so i really don't know what is causing the problem.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Also make sure '<?xml'  is at the beginning of the file, no spaces no lines before that.

Answer (score 0):

First attribute in TextView node must have a name, now it has only namespaсe **android**
See attentively at string:

```
android:="@+id/question_text_view"
```

Comment: That line is not valid, remove it